# How to make docker-compose volumes work on Hyper-V?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyper-v

I'm trying to run an application that uses volumes, but I get an error saying it couldn't find `package.json`.

```
10 error path /usr/src/app/package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -2
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
14 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
14 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
15 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

What do I have to do so it find the files?

Currently using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker 1.11.1-beta10 (build 2446)

Note: The same application works on docker for linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow docker to access your drivers. Go to:

- Settings...
- Manage shared drivers...
- Select the driver where you want to create the volume
- Enter your credentials

[image: enable drivers]